# Updating record in database, changes all when need it to change only 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

Sorry this is an update on my last post which i deleted as it was not explained very well.

I am displaying all rows from a database by username and status. I want to add a button to each row that will change the status from 'open' to 'running'.

Here is my code so far but it changes all the rows with the particular username and i just need it to change only the row that the user presses the button for:

```
 <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['running1'])) {
            $getid = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `event` WHERE `username` = '". $user_data['username'] ."'");
            while($gatherid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getid)) {
                $id = $gatherid['id'];

                mysql_query("UPDATE `event` SET `status` = 'running' WHERE `id` = '". $id ."'");
            }

        } else {
            mysql_error();
        }

        $event = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `status` = 'open' AND `username` = '". $user_data['username'] ."'");
            while($get_event = mysql_fetch_assoc($event)) {
                $venue        = $get_event['venue'];
                $title        = $get_event['title'];
                $status       = $get_event['status'];
                $available    = $get_event['numbershare'];
                $price        = $get_event['individual_price'];
                $id           = $get_event['id'];



            echo '
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>' . $venue . '</td>
                            <td>' . $title . '</td>
                            <td>' . $available . '</td>
                            <td>' . $price . '</td>
                            <td>' . $status . '</td>
                            <td><button class="btn-u">Link</button></td>
                            <td><form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" class="btn-u" name="running1"></form></td>                        
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>';
        }
```

?>

Comment: Do you know what the actual query being executed is?

Comment: Yes its changing all rows in the events database to have a status of running

Comment: I mean the `SQL`, like the text of the query being executed (not the description of the result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) add a hidden field in your form to track the id

```
<input type="hidden" value="' . $id . "'>
```

2) update your getid part to

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

3) execute the update

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `event` SET `status` = 'running' WHERE `id` = '". $id ."'") or throw Exception(mysql_error());
```